# Printing Binary Tree per Layer in a List

Tags: haskell

The function should print the markings of the argument tree in layers as a list of layers. The node and leaf markings in each layer are listed from left to right, that is, which is the most left node of the layer, the first element of the list, the right-most node is the last element of the list. The argument of type Ord indicates whether the layers in ascending order from the smallest to the largest layer (TopDown) or in descending order from largest to smallest layer (BottomUp) are to be issued

```
data Tree = Leaf Integer | Node Integer Tree Tree

type Layer = [Integer]

data Ord = BottomUp | TopDown

wLayer :: Tree -> Ord -> [Layer]
```

Example 1: We call the function wLayer with arguments
wLayer (Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf 21) (Leaf 22)) (Node 3 (Leaf 31) (Leaf 32))) TopDown
the result : [[1],[2,3],[21,22,31,32]]

Example 2:
wLayer (Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf 21) (Leaf 22)) (Node 3 (Leaf 31) (Leaf 32))) BottomUp
the result: [[21,22,31,32],[2,3],[1]]

how can i implement this one ?

**Edit**

```
data Tree = Leaf Integer
          | Node Integer Tree Tree
type Layer = [Integer]
data Ord   = BottomUp | TopDown

writeLayer :: Tree -> Ord -> [Layer]
writeLayer Leaf x = [x]
writeLayer (Node x lt rt) BottomUp = (writeLayer rt BottomUp) ++ [x] ++ (writeLayer lt BottomUp)
writeLayer (Node x lt rt) TopDown  = [x] ++ (writeLayer lt TopDown) ++ (writeLayer rt TopDown)
```

this is my program but it isn't work  how can i fix it ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of accomplishing this. It takes all of the nodes at a level and extracts the integer value from them, and then recurses on all of the children of these same nodes. After that, you match on `Ord` to determine if you need to reverse the list.

```
writeLayer t o =
    case o of
        BottomUp -> reverse $ makeLayer [t]
        TopDown -> makeLayer [t]
    where
        extract (Node i _ _) = i
        extract (Leaf i) = i
        children (Node _ a b) = [a, b]
        children _ = []
        makeLayer [] = []
        makeLayer ts = map extract ts : (makeLayer $ concat $ map children ts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

- the case where the `Tree` is a `Leaf` is trivial
- the difference between `BottomUp` and `TopDown` seems to be whether you reverse the list of `Layer`s
- when the `Tree` is a `Node` you will have to recurse on the subtrees and combine the results somehow

**Edit:** OK, let's concentrate on the first of these.

The equation you have for this case is

```
writeLayer Leaf x = [x]
```

First, the `Leaf x` needs to be in parentheses, because it's a single `Tree` value.

```
writeLayer (Leaf x) = [x]
```

Second, the equation needs to reflect that `writeLayer` takes *two* parameters (as written above, it takes only one). With a `Leaf` value, we don't care which order the results are to be returned in --- we give the same answer either way --- but we still have to take the parameter. We use `_` to signal that we don't care above the parameter and aren't going to use it.

```
writeLayer (Leaf x) _ = [x]
```

Thirdly, `[x]` is a (single element) list of `Integer`s --- but we are supposed to be returning a list of `Layer`s. I'm sure you can figure out how to fix this.

Finally, pay attention to the error messages the computer gives you. Understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer gives a corecursive definition of level-order traversal - an unfold to lists. (Exercise: write `makeLayer` using `Data.List.unfoldr`.) That's my favourite way too; see [The Underappreciated Unfold](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/publications/publication2351-abstract.html).

But it can also be done recursively - as a fold on trees. These are defined by analogy with `foldr` on lists as follows:

```
foldt :: (Integer->a) -> (Integer->a->a->a) -> Tree -> a
foldt f g (Leaf n)     = f n
foldt f g (Node n t u) = g n (foldt f g t) (foldt f g u)
```

Then level-order traversal is given by a straightforward tree fold, with a possible `reverse`:

```
wLayer :: Tree -> Order -> [Layer] 
wLayer t o = (if o==BottomUp then reverse else id) (foldt single glue t)
```

I took the liberty of renaming your flag type `Order` to a void a name clash, and making it an instance of `Eq`:

```
data Order = BottomUp | TopDown deriving Eq
```

The function `single` makes the level-order traversal of a leaf:

```
single :: Integer -> [Layer]
single n = [[n]]
```

whereas `glue` combines a label and the traversals of two children into the traversal of a node:

```
glue :: Integer -> [Layer] -> [Layer] -> [Layer]
glue n x y = [n] : longzipwith (++) x y
```

The crucial ingredient is a function `longzipwith`, which is like `zipWith` except that (i) the length of the result is the length of the longer argument, not the shorter, and hence (ii) the binary operator has to be `a->a->a`:

```
longzipwith :: (a->a->a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
longzipwith f (a:x) (b:y) = f a b : longzipwith f x y
longzipwith f x     []    = x
longzipwith f []    y     = y
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my program yet

```
data Tree = Leaf Integer
    | Node Integer Tree Tree
type Layer = [Integer]
data DOrd   = BottomUp | TopDown
writeLayer :: Tree -> DOrd -> [Integer]
writeLayer (Leaf x) _ = [x]
writeLayer (Node x lt rt) BottomUp = (writeLayer rt BottomUp) ++ [x] ++ (writeLayer lt BottomUp)
writeLayer (Node x lt rt) TopDown  = [x] ++ (writeLayer lt TopDown) ++ (writeLayer rt TopDown)
```

Calls:

```
*Main> writeLayer (Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf 21) (Leaf 22)) (Node 3 (Leaf 31) (Leaf 32))) TopDown
[1,2,21,22,3,31,32]
*Main> writeLayer (Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf 21) (Leaf 22)) (Node 3 (Leaf 31) (Leaf 32))) BottomUp
[32,3,31,1,22,2,21]
```

but i want to take first : [[1],[2,3],[21,22,31,32]]

second : [[21,22,31,32],[2,3],[1]]